# Detect pirated software on my personal computer

Tags: windows, legal

I got a used laptop, and I would like to know if there is any software that scans or detects which software I have installed are pirates or illegal.

I asked this question because in a company where I worked few years ago, the IT security staff scanned the company's computers detecting all illegal or pirated software (all this for legal issues of licensing). I never knew how they did it, maybe with software with license of payment, for big companies, I don't know, but I want to know if exists free software or somenthing like that, even not free. I want to know which software does something similar.

All this just for my personal computer.

The operating system is Windows 10.

Comment: You would trust a load of software on a used laptop from an unknown source?  No... I only put licensed software on there... wanna see my copy of the license for the keylogger and the sniffer that tracks logins on pages that use SSL?  Get a DVD of Windows, wipe, reinstall using the license key on the laptop.

Comment: Yes, I have in mind that and I am aware, but that is not the case, @ivanivan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WinAudit](http://www.parmavex.co.uk/winaudit.html) by parmavex is a Free, Open Source, tool that will give you a list of all of the software installed on your system.

To quote: "WinAudit is an inventory utility for Windows computers. It creates a comprehensive report on a machine's configuration, hardware and software. WinAudit is free, open source and can be used or distributed by anyone. It is used by IT experts in academia, government, industry as well as security conscious professionals in the armed services, defence contractors, electricity generators and police forces."

Once you have the report it produces it is down to you to determine if you have valid licences for the items or to uninstall them.

**N.B.** By far the safest thing to do when you have bought a second hand computer, *both from the licencing side and many others,* is to reformat the drives, *use thorough not quick* and reinstall the operating system or install a new one. Many windows based computers come with a licence sticker that you can use but buying a copy of Windows is not that expensive and, *of course*, installing Linux is free & comes with some great software. That way you are ***really sure*** that you have a "clean machine" with no pirate software, viruses, malware, porn, seditious material, plans for devices that you shouldn't have, etc., etc.,...

Comment: Unless you've a BIOS virus or something, but they're really uncommon though…

Comment: Thank you very much, @Steve Barnes, thats the kind of answer that I was looking for. I will try WinAudit...

Answer (score 0):

No,

if there was, then it would have really little use, since pirated software is hidden, since the point of piracy is to get the pro version or such and then don't let the software know, it's pirated. Otherwise the software would lock down and the pirating would fail.

It's like I have software. I want the pro version. I crack it. If the app detects it, it would shut down or disable itself, since who dev wants people stealing? It's like a burgarly alarm. If however something is pirated, then it is done hidden, like a robot in a house stealing things, **undetected** by the alarm. And now how will other software (neighbour) say there is a tiny robot inside the next house, if there is no alarm? I don't know how you got it, but I explained the best I could.

Comment: Hi, Kristofer Vesi. I understand the point, but I asked this question because in a company where I worked few years ago, the IT security staff scanned the company's computers detecting all illegal or pirated software (all this for legal issues of licensing). I never knew how they did it, maybe with software with license of payment, for big companies, I don't know, but I want to know if exists free software or somenthing like that, even not free. I want to know which software does something similar.

Comment: Well I think it might be something like Malwarebytes, since pirated things downloaded from the internet, have a big bundle of malware, tied to them. It might be that. I get the point, why ppl want to do it.

Comment: @Morquecho.String You should edit your question to add your explanation from your above comment.

Comment: agree, about the moving. Also @SteveBarnes I forgot to mention in my post, that yes there probably are some software, what lists software, but that can be achieved by the control panel uninstall. Maybe it checks for office and windows license, but that can be achieved manually too. Also if I was seller I would wipe the disk and as seller or buyer) reinstall windows, deleting all partitions. It is the best anti malware since nothing is left behind. But you can absolutely **Never** be sure. (some of this comment should be on he's answer, I lack rep on this SE I will move it to there if I can)